# How to use Google Cloud Pub/Sub as Laravel Queue Driver

Tags: php, laravel, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

So I was following this [tutorial](https://alex-desmet.medium.com/using-pub-sub-as-a-laravel-queue-driver-1ff9223c5fde) on how to use pub sub as Laravel queue driver. but I am stuck as I was trying to run the worker with php artisan queue:work --queue=clcej which showed error

`No connector for [pubsub]`

this is the lines I added at my config/queue.php

```
        'default' => env('QUEUE_CONNECTION', 'pubsub'),
        'pubsub' => [
            'driver' => 'pubsub',
            'queue' => 'clcej',
            'queue_prefix' => env('PUBSUB_QUEUE_PREFIX', ''),
            'project_id' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID', 'ciputra-nusantara'),
            'retries' => 3,
            'request_timeout' => 60,
        ],
```

I am still confused because in the tutorial there is no step where I have to set up the pub/sub in GCP

or is there easier and efficient way to run a queue worker on a serverless environment ?

Comment: The guide in your post does not show the steps to set up Pub/Sub. You will need to set up a Pub/Sub Topic to push messages to and a Pub/Sub Subscription to read the messages from. Probably any guide that shows how to create a Pub/Sub Topic and Subscription should work. Try to official guides: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/admin and https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/create-subscription

Answer (score 3):

Cloud Pub/Sub requires messages to be published to “topics” and then delivered to consumers using “subscriptions”.  Our [overview documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview) can help you understand topic and subscription concepts. Both topics and subscriptions need to be created before they can be used.

The [configuration section](https://github.com/kainxspirits/laravel-pubsub-queue#configuration) of the library docs indicate that you may need to change the `queue` section of your configuration to be `'queue' => env('PUBSUB_QUEUE', 'clcej'),`.

Alternatively our [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publish-receive-messages-console) can help you create topics/subscriptions on the Google Cloud console.

Or, you may use the [gcloud CLI](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud) and follow the steps outlined in the  [gcloud quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publish-receive-messages-gcloud) to:

Create a topic with the ID `my-topic`

```
gcloud pubsub topics create my-topic
```

Create a subscription with the ID `my-sub` and attach it to my-topic:

```
gcloud pubsub subscriptions create my-sub --topic=my-topic
```

You can retry the tutorial after creating the topic/subscription.

Answer (score 0):

Might be it is too late to reply. But, you can use https://packagist.org/packages/munir131/laravel-pubsub-queue which is fork of kainxspirits/laravel-pubsub-queue and we are using that for many years in production.